# Determine memory consumption

Tags: c++, memory

In C++, with this:

```
std::time_t first  = time(NULL);
/* .. code .. */
std::time_t second = time(NULL);

std::cout << "Seg : " << difftime(second,first) << std::endl;
```

I can determine my program's execution duration.

Can I determine its memory consumption at different points through the program?

Comment: For what platform? You're going to have to write something platform specific to do this...

Comment: Are you talking about stack space, or heap memory?

Comment: @EboMike: Or perhaps he's using an environment that employs something other than a heap for the free store. The language doesn't care what it is.

Comment: Override the basic `new` operators and count the memory used. Voila, you got your mechanism ;) ... you can also use profilers with or without instrumentation to achieve the same.

Comment: You can read your own `/proc/self/statm`, see `man proc`. You should be aware that a program doesn't normally release memory to the operating system when a `free`, `realloc`-down or `delete` is done... it only grows memory when more is needed. Linux is a bit smarter, and may special case really big allocations, releasing them before process termination.  Consequently, it will be more useful to concentrate on which program steps caused memory to grow suddenly.

Comment: @Tomalak: Prescriptive pedantry much? :)

Comment: @GMan: How many milligrams do you want, sir? Sincerely, Doctor C++

Comment: @EboMike both, stack space, or heap memory.

Answer (score 2):

[Not easily.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563168/monitor-a-programs-memory-usage-in-linux)