# how to monitor a processes memory usage over time - ubuntu

Tags: linux, memory, ubuntu, monitoring

I want to watch a given process in unix over time to see what time memory grows (its a long running job)

I guess I could do

```
ps -aux | grep PID
```

and run this from cron every 5 minutes, but it seems there should be a better way.

Is there a way I can use sar to do this?

Comment: your question belongs on ubuntu or superuser

Comment: I was thinking about this, but its from a developers point of view and its a development problem, my process is leaking memory, im not an SA....I guess I can try over there, but it seems relevant on both...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563168/monitor-a-programs-memory-usage-in-linux ?  Also suggest using `top` with `-p -b -d` options.

Comment: @Joelio - there are tools that can monitor for leaks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I use the following:

```
$ ps -o rss $(pgrep executablename)
```

Put that in a while loop or use watch to monitor it over time coupled with tail. You can also tee it to a file and have gnuplot plot it for you and refresh it every few seconds.

Comment: Incorrect answer. RSS isn't memory usage.

Comment: @poige, what do you mean?? - RSS
    Real-memory (resident set) size in kilobytes of the process. This number is equal to the sum of the number of working segment and code segment pages in memory times 4. Remember that code segment pages are shared among all of the currently running instances of the program. If 26 ksh processes are running, only one copy of any given page of the ksh executable program would be in memory, but the ps command would report that code segment size as part of the RSS of each instance of the ksh program.

Comment: Process can be swapped (paged) out partly, and its RSS would be less, actually.

Comment: If executablename is not running the above is equivalent to just `ps -o rss`.  Using `-p` before the PID list seems safer as it asks explicitly for PIDS, thus would fail instead.