# I need create a script to generate log command TOP

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have that generate a history of server's memory and cpu used. But i can't install any software on server.

Then i am trying this script

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
 date >> system.log
 top -n1 | grep 'Cpu\|Mem\|java\|eservices' >> system.log
 echo '' >> system.log
 sleep 2
done
```

but when i try execute tail -500f system.log  the logs stopping

Comment: This script will run forever until you stop it. How are you doing the test? Are you sure the script is still running?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the script finish". What do you actually run, what do you see, and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I want run the script in background. After i will generate a report with the data

./script.sh &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use the `-b` batch mode parameter. From `man top`:

> Starts top in 'Batch' mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or to a file.   In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the '-n' command-line option or until killed.

You might want to use the portable format `tail -n 500 -f`.

In any case, saving `top` output to file and then running `tail -f` on it emulates the way `top` works. What are you trying to achieve that `top` does not do already?

Comment: I want generate a history of used memory on server and a specific process. There must be a better way, but I can not install anything on the server.

Answer (score 1):

To monitor total free memory use on a server, you can

```
grep -F MemFree: /proc/meminfo
```

To [monitor process memory use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278326/how-to-monitor-a-processes-memory-usage-over-time-ubuntu):

```
ps -o rss $pid
```